# Overcoming vbe in a low voltage application

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to drive a motor with a sinusoid from a DAC.

DAC can't drive the motor directly. Motor is a 2.3 - 3.6V motor with a peak current of 120mA. DAC max voltage is 3.6 with a weak drive strength. My supply voltage is 3.7V

I would like to maximize my the voltage that goes to the motor, but I can't see a way to overcome the BE or EB junction of BJTs (example shown below) That 0.6V drop is ~ 17% of my voltage range.

What circuit topologies are available that would maximize the voltage range going to the motor (and drive current) ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUYxVJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**edit**
Default values from schematic tool removed show general topology vs the actual circuit.

Comment: You need to have analog control over the voltage applied to the motor? Would a low side switch with PWM work?

Comment: Did you try to use mosfet instead?

Comment: @ThePhoton I have it setup for the PWM, but also want to experiment with analog so I'd like to have both with a jump that would select which mode (PWM / DAC).

Comment: This is unlikely to work well at low speeds.

Comment: A TL081 is never going to work with a 3.7 V supply.

Comment: @OlinLathrop should have stated that the opamp selected in the schematic was whatever the default was. I have a RRIO opamp selected with the appropriate range.

Comment: Then **show that in the schematic!**  We only know what the schematic shows.  Your schematic is currently very misleading if you are not actually using a TL081.

Comment: @efox29 So how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution:

- Replace the NPN with a PNP transistor or a P-MOSFET.
- Swap non-inverting input with inverting input on the op-amp.
- Add a 100 Ω resistor between the output of the op-amp and the base of PNP for safety. Skip this if you're using a P-MOSFET.

---

Perhaps you can't acquire a PNP or a P-MOSFET, in that case just let the op-amp perform some math for you so everything will be fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faBXTq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This way the op-amp will perform this expression, \$V_{motor}=V_{DAC}\$, if there wouldn't have been any math and you'd just swap the NPN transistor with the motor then it would've been \$V_{motor}=3.7-V_{DAC}\$.

---

### EDIT

Andy Aka pointed out that that the schematic above will oscillate. So I tried that schematic out on a breadboard but with an N-MOSFET instead of an NPN and he was right. It oscillated at 180 kHz.

However after attaching a 3.3 µF capacitor from ground to drain, or collector in the schematic above if I'd use an NPN transistor, the problem disappeared. But Andy Aka doesn't think it's reliable.

With that said, don't use my design if your device that you are making has life threatening elements in it.

I won't delete this answer because the first part of the answer clearly says "*quick and **dirty** solution*".

Comment: Also add a resistor between the output and non-inverting input(1k-ish, only current in it is the opamp bias current), and a capacitor (100p?), to compensate for the gain you've added.

Comment: @τεκ What would otherwise happen? Oscillations?

Comment: This circuit is not a good suggestion. You are multiplying the beta of the transistor by the open loop gain of the op-amp and expecting that negative feedback will solve everything - it won't. It will oscillate.

Comment: @Andyaka I've just built the circuit on a bread board but with an N-MOSFET rather than a NPN and you were right, it was oscillating at 180 kHz. But after adding a 3.3 µF capacitor from ground to drain, or collector in the NPN case, the oscillations disappeared and it worked like in the simulations, perfectly.

Comment: @HarrySvensson the trick is with these circuits is knowing whether something can be relied on with all manner of different load conditions.  A motor is going to present a wide range of impedances and resistances that vary with mechanical loading. How far your additions are from a possible point of instability is un-proven. Do you see the problems I see?

Comment: @Andyaka I've just tried with a small DC motor and it wouldn't work without the capacitor. - It *looked* fine to me, its voltage was correct. I even stopped the shaft and let go and it worked as *expected*. But maybe it only works because this is an N-MOSFET (AO3402) rather than an NPN with some high \$\beta\$. - So I assume my "*quick and dirty solution*" is also problematic in your eyes?

Comment: @HarrySvensson this sort of circuit inevitably need careful consideration of what the capacitor does. It's probably more reliable to have a capacitor directly around the op-amp thus limiting the open loop gain and avoiding the 2nd pole phase shift inside the op-amp when the gain is higher than unity. The drain-ground capacitor *could* form a tuned circuit with motor inductance so I would advise against it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't try to do this linearly.

   Don't try to do this with a BJT.

Try this:

[image]

The motor is always either driven full on or full off.  To get in-between control, you switch between on and off rapidly enough that the motor doesn't "see" the pulses, only the average.  This is called *pulse width modulation*, or PWM for short.

The main advantage is that very little power is dissipated in the driver.  The switch (Q1 in the above circuit) is most of the time fully off (no current), or fully on (very little voltage).  Either way, it dissipates little power.

This FET also goes to 37 mΩ when driven with 2.5 V on the gate.  At your maximum current of 120 mA, it will drop less than 5 mV, or about 0.12% of the supply voltage.  It will dissipate about half a milliwatt, which is so little you'll be unable to notice the temperature rise with a finger.

A PWM frequency in the 24 to 30 kHz range is usually good for motors.  The motor mechanism responds much more slowly than that, but this is above human hearing to avoid audible whine.  You also want the current thru the coils of the motor to be fairly steady and not go up and down too much each cycle.

Producing PWM from a control value is trivial nowadays.  Most of the time that control value will be digital anyway, so it's just a matter of doing a little conversion in the microcontroller.  Just about every micro has PWM output capability.  There are many that have plenty of duty cycle resolution left at 25 kHz PWM frequency.

For example, let's say you wanted 8 bit control (256 effective drive levels) at 25 kHz.  That requires only a 6.4 MHz clock to the PWM module.

The rest is firmware.

There are also stand-alone chips available that make PWM with a duty cycle proportional to a analog input voltage.  However, PWM is basically free in the micro that is inevitably there anyway.

Comment: If you read the comments under his/her question, s/he already got PWM working. s/he purposely wanted to drive it linearly.

Comment: @Harry: Comments aren't content.  You can't expect the volunteers here to read comments to get pertinent information to the question.

Comment: I have the PWM circuit already. Was looking for the linear approach. Good information regardless.

Comment: @efo: Then you need to **add that to your question**.

Comment: @OlinLathrop my *question* was about *overcoming vbe* and *other* topologies to maximize voltage range across motor. Your answer dismisses the question and goes into PWM. It's one approach sure - but my question was about driving the motor with a sinusoid from a dac and maximizing the voltage range with my limitations.

Comment: First, using the MOSFET as I show directly overcomes the Vbe issues.  Second, I'm addressing the overall problem, not the narrow one you asked about.  You are starting with a digital value since you are driving a D/A.  I'm starting from there to solve the problem you stated, not the imagined solution you came up with.  Put another way, the answer to *How do I get around xxx?* is *Don't do yyy in the first place.*

Answer (score 1):

> What circuit topologies are available that would maximize the voltage
>   range going to the motor (and drive current) ?

With only a 3.7 volt battery and a requirement to drive up to 3.6 volt onto the motor I'd be tempted to build a low power supply voltage booster. I would stick with the general idea of a BJT (or MOSFET) emitter (or source) follower to enhance the output power of the op-amp because it is a much stabler solution than a common-emitter (or source) circuit for reasons I gave on another answer. The reason it is stabler is because a voltage follower has unity gain or less and won't shift phase so much to pose an oscillation problem when the loop is closed.

I'd be tempted by something like this: -

[image]

It's going to running at nearly 90% efficiency so most applications should be OK I would suggest but, do check your battery life calculations.

I would also consider using a rail-to-rail op-amp for the motor drive circuit and, given the low power nature of the motor I reckon a BJT would be preferred. Check the heat dissipated by the BJT - with it delivering 50% voltage (2.5 volts) at 120 mA, dissipation is 300 mW and some small heatsinking might be required.

Comment: This seems more and more like the way to go. Accept the loss of the vbe but compensate by having a slightly higher voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Use a PNP instead of an NPN and swap the inputs, but don't forget to compensate for the extra gain. Here C1 sends any high frequency directly to the input, slowing the opamp's response, and miller-multiplied C2 slows down Q2 by as much.

To calculate actual values for these is not so easy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp6e4V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what linear control topology you choose (NPN or PNP) you will need at least 200 mV \$V_{CE}\$ to keep the transistor out of saturation and maintain forward current gain \$\beta\$.

So, best case scenario is a peak output of 3.5 V for your 3.6 V motor.

A simple charge pump to give OA1 an extra 400 mV of headroom while keeping the collector of Q1 sourced to the battery, would be the simplest way to add a bit more output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your circuit does not go to the rail is because you are using a voltage follower.

The trick is to switch things around and use an inverting driver like the one below. Note the inputs to the op-amp are reversed from your original solution. Because M1 adds an inversion to the circuit, (the voltage on the motor goes higher when the op-amp output goes lower), it effectively changes the op-amp pins around.

As long as you chose a MOSFET with a sufficiently low Vgs this circuit should drive rail to rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKJ79O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also use a PNP instead of the MOSFET, but the op-amp needs to be able to pull sufficient base current to be amplified to the desired motor current.

*NOTE: This type of circuit can oscillate and as such some additional components and tuning may be required to get it to operate correctly.*

Comment: Trev, check other answers/comments re stability of this type of circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka ya I was wondering about that.

Comment: ... possibly the extended hangover lol

Comment: @Andyaka damn son-in-law kept filling up my Scotch..  Anyhow, the concept is still sound, but I added a note on tuning, hard to say what it needs with a specific motor and mosfet.